# Scaling Sphere in uneven dimensions

Tags: graphics

I have a sphere that I am placing in a graph that has uneven dimensions and as a result it looks like a flattened disk. I imagine that some scaling command might allow me to show it properly. I offer an example code. My real code has many spheres being placed in a range from `{2,139,0}` to `{4,170,1}`. The coordinates of the spheres are in the coordinates of that space, therefore I do not want to scale the coordinates, I only want to scale the radius. Unless an easy way exists to inverse scale the coordinates.

```
Graphics3D[{
  Polygon[{
    {0, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, 10, 0}}],
  Sphere[{.5, 5, .5}, .4]
  },
 Axes -> True,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Comment: You could use `Ellipsoid` instead of sphere. Then you'd probably want to extract the aspect ratio of the plot (or set it by hand) and use appropriate semi-axes.

Comment: `Graphics3D[{
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 0}}],
  Sphere[{.5, 5, .5}, .4]}, Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}, {0, 1}},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 10, 1}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plotrange = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} = {{0, 1}, {0, 10}, {0, 1}};
r = 0.4;
Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 0}}], 
  Ellipsoid[{.5, 5, .5}, {b - a, d - c, f - e} r]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> plotrange, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

---

The same works for a number of spheres/ellipsoids:

```
plotrange = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} = {{2, 4}, {139, 170}, {0, 1}};
n = 10; (* number of spheres *)
r = RandomReal[0.2, n]; (* radii of the spheres *)
pts = Table[{RandomReal[{a, b}], RandomReal[{c, d}], RandomReal[{e, f}]}, {i, 1, n}];
    (* centers of the spheres *)
ellipsoids = Table[Ellipsoid[pts[[i]], {b - a, d - c, f - e} r[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]; 
           (*suitably scaled spheres/ellipsoids *)

Graphics3D[
 Join[{Polygon[{{2, 139, 0}, {4, 139, 0}, {2, 170, 0}}]}, ellipsoids],
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> plotrange, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, Corey! Many thanks.